# How can I document a variable required by a method with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Should I do something like this?

```
/**
* Constructor function
*
* @contructor
* @param {Number} x - a number.
*/
function foo(x){
    this.x = x;
    /**
     * Sum to x.
     * @param {Number} y - A number.
     * @param {Object} this - The bar.
     * @param {Number} this.x - A number [requered].
     */
    this.bar(y) {
        return this.x + y;
    }
}
```

Or in this case I shouldn't define in the comment the required definition of `this.x`.

Comment: Namepaths might give a solution, see the [*documentation*](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you document your code, you **shouldn't disclose  what are the internals of your methods to the "outside"**. Just document your methods properly and correctly what each method:

- does
- accepts (if any)
- and returns (if any)

...in concise forms.

But if you want to document the internals of your objects, you can use the `@private` or `@protected` tags.

[JSDoc tags as "accessibility modifiers"](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-private.html#related-links)

---

**More like this:**

```
/**
 * Constructs foo, that does something useful.
 *
 * @contructor
 * @param {number} x - A number, which determines X.
 */
function foo(x){
    /*
     * An important number.
     *
     * @private
     * @type {number}
     */
    this._x = x;        

    /**
     * Returns the summary of X and Y.
     *
     * @param {number} y - A number to add to X.
     * @returns {number} The summary of X and Y.
     */
    this.bar(y){
        return this._x + y;
    }
}
```

This way, when you are using a type-checker or an IDE, you will be notified in case you've ignored a required argument.

---

JavaScript documentation options:

- [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)
- [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org/)

For typed JavaScript, check out:

- [flow](https://flow.org/en/)
- [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

---

[**Usage of JSDoc**](http://usejsdoc.org/index.html)